# How can I use `vector <unsigned int*> vec;` properly

Tags: pointers, vector, int

I am new in C++ and I want to use `vector <unsigned int*> vec;`

I try this code:

```
vector <unsigned int*> vec;
unsigned int* tmpV= new unsigned int[4];
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<4;i++){
        tmpV[i]=i;
    }

vec.push_back(tmpV);
unsigned int* tmpV2=vec.at(0);
cout<<"A) tmpV2[1]: "<<tmpV2[1] <<endl;
cout<<"vec.size(): "<<vec.size()<<endl;

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<4;i++){
        tmpV[i]=i+4;

    }
vec.push_back(tmpV);
tmpV2=vec.at(0);
cout<<"vec.size(): "<<vec.size()<<endl;
cout<<"B) tmpV2[1]: "<<tmpV2[1]<<endl;
```

The problem her is that I wanted to output the same value for A) and B)
but it ouputs
A) tmpV2[1]: 1
B) tmpV2[1]: 5

I want to be able to handle different elements in this vector of pointers.
I can roughly understand why this is going on but I couldn't find a solution.

Have in mind that I don't want to use: `vector < vector <unsigned int> >`

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have incremented the value pointed by the pointer at the index a in vector

> vec

if you reprint it again after printing

```
 valuecout<<"B) tmpV2[1]: "<<tmpV2[1]<<endl
valuecout<<"B) tmpV2[1]: "<<vec[1] <<endl
```

both will show same result

What you have done so far is

You have a vector of integer pointers

You have initialized this array

You had one temporary pointer pointing to the zeroth index of the vector

Now using this pointer you printed the value pointed by the second index of the vec

After that you manipulated all the values pointed by vector of pointers (incremented by 4)

Now you are again printing the value pointed by index 1 of vector

Both are same only thing is you printed the value manipulated it and again printed after manipulation. If you reprint both *vec[1] and tmpV2[1]  at the end again you will find both are same.